# How can I store already aggregated by time samples in influxdb?

Tags: python, metrics, influxdb, grafana

I collecting metrics samples from 'clients' in agregated by the time interval format like e.g:

`{ 'interval': 19:50-19:55, 'hits': 55, 'missed': 45}
{ 'interval': 19:55-20:00, 'hits': 23, 'missed': 15}`

How can I store and use it in influxdb? I looked examples of influxdb usage and notice that always used specific time of sampes, e.g. 19:55:01, not interval.

Answer (score 1):

one work-around would be store the starting time point as time stamp, and the duration of the interval as a value. If you intervals are all evenly-spaced and continuous, there's probably no need to store the duration at all.